# Swift string to Hex (Not Array)

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I want to create a Type(tag), Length, Value (TLV) byte array.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value

This TLV would be an [UInt8] array where the first two elements are the type/tag and length, and the remaining element is the bytes of an encoded string.  E.g. "Hello, world."

I am doing this in Swift.

I want the value part to be a viable length string.

I can create a type(tag) and a length easily.  For instance:

```
let tag: UInt8    = 0x02
let length: UInt8 = 0x01
```

When I create a byte array from the string in the following manner:

```
let str = "Yo, El Mundo"
let buf = [UInt8](str.utf8)
```

I get a proper array.  However when I try to add it to the [UInt8] array I get the following error from Xcode:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[UInt8]' to expected element type 'UInt8'
```

To be very clear here is the code that produces this error:

```
let tag: UInt8   = 0x02
let length: UInt8 = 0x01

let str = "Yo, El Mundo"
let buf = [UInt8](str.utf8)
print("the buf is: \(buf)")
// the buf is: [89, 111, 44, 32, 69, 108, 32, 77, 117, 110, 100, 111]

let bytes:[UInt8] = [tag, length, buf]

// Error: Cannot convert value of type '[UInt8]' to expected element type 'UInt8'
```

Here's the part I am not knowledgable on.  I was assuming that the problem was the format. I.e. I was assuming the problem was I was trying to put "[89, 111, 44, 32, 69, 108, 32, 77, 117, 110, 100, 111]" in the array instead of "0x01".

But perhaps I just don't understand something else.  I am totally new to working in bytes so I'm still learning what I don't know.

Do I need to figure out a way to get the byte array into the smaller hex format?

Am I missing something else?

Just looking for a little direction.

Apologies for not being clear.  Doing the best I know how - which is why I'm asking here.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by *"create a hex from that string"*?

Comment: Looks like you want a `[UInt8]` where the first two elements are the `tag` and `length`, and the remaining elements are the bytes of the encoded string (please be explicit about what encoding you want to use, your code says UTF-8 though). Although I would just start off with `Data`rather than `[UInt8]`, then converting to `Data`. Also note that hex is just a way of *presenting* bytes in a human-readable way (as is decimal) – it's got nothing to do with how they're stored in memory. They're just zeroes and ones at the end of the day (and even that is still just a way of presenting them).

Comment: `[89, 111, 44, 32, 69, 108, 32, 77, 117, 110, 100, 111]` is a decimal representation of a bunch of bits of storage. "hex" isn't a way of storing things, it's a way of **representing** them.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a string into a single byte? What is a TLV? Again, your question is really unclear.

Comment: OK.  As I suspected there are things I don't understand even enough to make a clear question.  Hamish you are giving me a path to start my learning on.  Sorry to lead you all down a rabbit hole.  I'll go learn more and return with better questions or answers.

Comment: Changed the verbiage of the question since it seems to be getting in the way - even though I'm going to go try and learn more in order to ask better questions.

Comment: In a more explicit way explaining your error: `var bytes = [UInt8].init(); bytes.append(tag); bytes.append(length); bytes.append(contentsOf: buf)`  As you see, `buf` is already a `[UInt8]`, so I used `append(contentOf:)` instead to append one by one each elements.. So if you did `[tag, length, buf]`, that would have been a `[FirstUInt8, SecondUInt8, ArrayOfUInt8]`, so it needed to be declared a `[Any]`: `let bytes2:[Any] = [tag, length, buf]` (print both, you'll se the difference).

Comment: Thank you Larme for the clarity on the error.  That helped me understand what I did not previously understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `buf` variable, its type is `[UInt8]`, not `UInt8` which is the expected. Also you can create an `extension` for `Data` or `[UInt8]` to create the hex representation. The code below correctly join the data as you wish.

```
import Foundation

extension Data {
    var hex: String {
        let stringDataParts = self.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }
        let stringData = stringDataParts.joined()
        return stringData
    }
}

let tag: UInt8   = 0x02
let length: UInt8 = 0x01

let str = "Yo, El Mundo"
let buf = [UInt8](str.utf8)
print("the buf is: \(buf)")
// the buf is: [89, 111, 44, 32, 69, 108, 32, 77, 117, 110, 100, 111]

let bytes:[UInt8] = [tag, length] + buf

print(bytes)
// [2, 1, 89, 111, 44, 32, 69, 108, 32, 77, 117, 110, 100, 111]

print(Data(bytes: bytes).hex)
// 0201596f2c20456c204d756e646f
```

Comment: Most excellent valcanaia!  Thank you for providing the information I was missing!  This was great.

So, for clarity, my personal misunderstanding was that the string had to be placed into an array.  That array needed to be joined and then appended onto the byte array.
Thank you so much for your help.  The code is working perfectly now.